Advices to install Ubuntu 24.04 LTS installation Help with EFI boost partitation
I think this problem is a mechanical problem. My laptop is an HP Elitebook 8460p, RAM 4GB and SSD 240GB. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is working fine.
Here is how I usually boot my laptop.
Boot from EFI file:

ACPI (PNPOAO3,O)/Pci(1F|2)/Sata(Part 0)/HD(Part2,Sig8D108702... etc. Maybe it's SSD name or something.

EFI:

Ubuntu:

grubx64.efi:

And then boot up. Ubuntu 22.04 is OK like that.
My 24.04 installation process:
First try
I made bootable stick with Startup Disk Creator and I plugin and reboot my laptop. Live Ubuntu is up and I did a fresh installation with the "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" option. Installation process is completely finish and I restart and unplug the stick, but the boot wasn't up and I got a bootable device not found error.
Second try
This time I made partition manually. I checked the layout of partition of 22.04 LTS(Working fine). This is like -
500MB | VFAT |  no mount point | esp,boot(flag) 
the rest of memory | ext4 | / | no flag

It doesn't work too.
Third try
I changed the layout of partition.
500MB | VFAT | no mount point | esp,boot(flag)
8GB | swap | 
the rest of memory | ext4 | / | no flag

This doesn't work either.
Fourth try
I changed the mount point.
500MB | VFAT | /boot | esp,boot(flag)
8GB | swap | 
the rest of memory | ext4 | / | no flag

Fifth try
I changed the mount point.
500MB | VFAT | /boot/efi | esp,boot(flag)
8GB | swap | 
the rest of memory | ext4 | / | no flag

According to my knowledge, there is only option for VFAT (instead of fat32) in 24.04 installer.
I'm a Linux beginner. How to install Ubuntu 24.04 in my situation?

What happens if you select the netbook hard drive? Vfat is ok.
